# Create boolean if all the months in a year are included in a column - Pyspark

Tags: python, date, pyspark

I want to create a boolean column where if a subset of a specific date column contains all the months in a year it returns True.

example:

```
id      date
a   2021-01-01
a   2021-02-01
...
a   2021-12-01
b   2021-02-01
b   2021-04-01
```

would look like:

```
id     date        full_year
a   2021-01-01        yes
a   2021-02-01        yes
...                   ...
a   2021-12-01        yes
b   2021-02-01         no
b   2021-04-01         no
```

Comment: Can the date repeat for each id?

Comment: Yes, it can repeat dates multiple times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imports:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window as W
```

---

Code:

```
w = W.partitionBy("id",F.year("date"))
out = (sdf.withColumn("date",F.to_date("date"))
.withColumn("CountYearMOnth",
F.size(F.collect_set(F.date_format("date","yyyyMM")).over(w)))
.withColumn("full_year",F.when(F.col("CountYearMOnth")==12,"yes").otherwise("No"))
.drop("CountYearMOnth")
      )
```

---

Logic:

1. Partition by id and year column and create a window (w)
2. convert date column to an actual date column (ignore if type is a date column)
3. collect set over the window (w) and get the size of date column with format yyyymm with the below condition
4. If size == 12, then assign Yes else assign No

Alternatively you can replace size of collect list with approx count distinct:

```
w = W.partitionBy("id",F.year("date"))
out = (sdf.withColumn("date",F.to_date("date"))
.withColumn("CountYearMOnth",
F.approx_count_distinct(F.date_format("date","yyyyMM")).over(w))
.withColumn("full_year",F.when(F.col("CountYearMOnth")==12,"yes").otherwise("No"))
.drop("CountYearMOnth")
      )
```

---

Sample output:

```
+---+----------+---------+
|id |date      |full_year|
+---+----------+---------+
|a  |2021-01-31|yes      |
|a  |2021-02-28|yes      |
|a  |2021-03-31|yes      |
|a  |2021-04-30|yes      |
|a  |2021-05-31|yes      |
|a  |2021-06-30|yes      |
|a  |2021-07-31|yes      |
|a  |2021-08-31|yes      |
|a  |2021-09-30|yes      |
|a  |2021-10-31|yes      |
|a  |2021-11-30|yes      |
|a  |2021-12-31|yes      |
|a  |2022-01-31|No       |
|a  |2022-02-28|No       |
|a  |2022-03-31|No       |
|a  |2022-04-30|No       |
|b  |2021-01-31|No       |
|b  |2021-02-28|No       |
|b  |2021-03-31|No       |
|b  |2021-04-30|No       |
|b  |2021-05-31|No       |
|b  |2021-06-30|No       |
+---+----------+---------+
```

Comment: Issue is counting months to 12, since if we have 3 months of 2021, full year in 2022 and 1 month of 2023; only 2022 should be yes.

Comment: @AntonioLópezRuiz I have edited to just do that, its collecting the distinct of a year and month to to 12, can you try and see if it works now?